# Como reduzir o bloco de instruções inserido dentro de um estrutura condicionante if em python?

Tags: python, if, tkinter

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um programa que calcula e dimensiona vigas-parede. Ele trabalha basicamente com verificações de segurança (solicitação menor ou igual a resistência), quando uma dessas verificações não for atendida, o programa emitirá um alerta ao usuário informando o erro e em seguida irá propor uma solução. Porém o bloco de instruções contido dentro desse if ficou bem grande e consequentemente vem originando alguns erros. Gostaria de saber como posso reduzir linhas desse código. (OBS: todo esse código está contido na função confirmar, o editor do site não representou do mesma maneira que copiei)

```
def confirmar():
lff = float(raid1.get()) * 0.01
h = float(raid2.get()) * 0.01
bw = float(raid3.get()) * 0.01
c1 = float(raid4.get()) * 0.01
c2 = float(raid5.get()) * 0.01
fck = float(raid6.get())
Gi = float(raid7.get())
Gs = float(raid8.get())
hf = float(raid9.get()) * 0.01
c = float(raid10.get()) * 0.01
c3 = float(raid13.get()) * 0.01

# Comprimento total
ltot = (lff + c1 + c2)

# Vão de eixo a eixo
lee = float(lff + c1 / 2 + c2 / 2)

# Relação vão altura
vh = (lee / h)

# Tipo de Viga
if vh >= 2:
    erro = tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Erro na verificação",
                                        "A Estrutura apresentada não se classifica como viga-parede")
    verificacao = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("XimeS - Cálculo de viga-parede", "Deseja informar novos dados?")
    if verificacao > 0:
        limpar()
    elif verificacao == 0:
        janela_principal.destroy()

# Vão teórico
le = min(lee, 1.15 * lff)
# print(f'#Vão teórico: \033[33m{le:.2f}m\033[m')

# Altura efetiva
he = min(le, h)
# print(f'#Altura efetiva: \033[33m{he:.2f}m\033[m')

# Carregamento
Q = (bw * h * 25) + Gi + Gs
# print(f'#Carregamento: \033[33m{Q:.2f} KN/m\033[m')

# Esforços Solicitantes
V = (Q * le) / 2
M = (Q * pow(le, 2)) / 8
# print(f'#Força Solicitante: \033[33m{V:.2f} KN\033[m')
# print(f'#Momento Máximo: \033[33m{M:.2f} KN.m\033[m')

# Verificação do Concreto
# Cisalhamento
fcd = (fck * 1000) / 1.4
Vrd = 0.20 * bw * he * fcd
Vd = 1.4 * V

# print(f'#Solicitação de Cálculo: \033[33m{Vd:.2f} KN\033[m')
# print(f'#Resistência ao Cisalhamento: \033[33m{Vrd:.2f} KN\033[m')
def bt_click_nao1():
    verificacao1.destroy()
    return

def bt_click_sim1():
    bt_sim1["state"] = "disabled"
    global raid11
    raid11 = IntVar()

    def ck1():
        ck_Afck["state"] = "disabled"
        en_fck["state"] = "disabled"
        global teste
        teste = 1
        return

    def ck2():
        ck_Alargura["state"] = "disabled"
        en_largura["state"] = "disabled"
        global teste
        teste = 2
        return

    def reset():
        ck_Alargura["state"] = "normal"
        ck_Afck["state"] = "normal"
        ck_Alargura.deselect()
        ck_Afck.deselect()
        en_largura["state"] = "normal"
        en_fck["state"] = "normal"
        en_largura.delete(first=0, last=11)
        en_fck.delete(first=0, last=11)
        return

    def confirmar1():
        verificacao1.destroy()

        if teste == 1:
            bw1 = raid11.get() * 0.01
            # Carregamento
            Q = (bw1 * h * 25) + Gi + Gs
            # print(f'#Novo Carregamento: \033[33m{Q:.2f} KN/m\033[m')

            # Esforços Solicitantes
            V = (Q * le) / 2
            M = (Q * pow(le, 2)) / 8
            # print(f'#Nova Cortante: \033[33m{V:.2f} KN\033[m')
            # print(f'#Novo Momento Máximo: \033[33m{M:.2f} KN.m\033[m')

            # Verificação do Concreto
            # Cisalhamento
            fcd = (fck * 1000) / 1.4
            Vrd = 0.20 * bw1 * he * fcd
            Vd = 1.4 * V
            print(f'#Nova cortante de cálculo: \033[33m{Vd:.2f} KN\033[m')
            print(f'#Nova resistênca de cálculo: \033[33m{Vrd:.2f} KN\033[m')

        if teste == 2:
            # Carregamento

            Q = (bw * h * 25) + Gi + Gs
            # print(f'#Novo Carregamento: \033[33m{Q:.2f} KN/m\033[m')

            # Esforços Solicitantes
            V = (Q * le) / 2
            M = (Q * pow(le, 2)) / 8
            # print(f'#Nova Cortante: \033[33m{V:.2f} KN\033[m')
            # print(f'#Novo Momento Máximo: \033[33m{M:.2f} KN.m\033[m')

            # Verificação do Concreto
            # Cisalhamento
            fcd = (fck * 1000) / 1.4
            vrd = 0.20 * bw * he * fcd
            Vd = 1.4 * V
            # print(f'#Nova cortante de cálculo: \033[33m{Vd:.2f} KN\033[m')
            # print(f'#Nova resistênca de cálculo: \033[33m{Vrd:.2f} KN\033[m')

            # Zona de Apoio
            Vd1 = Vd * 1.1
            Vrd1 = 0.8 * bw * (c1 + hf) * fcd
            print(f'Solicitação na zona de apoio: \033[33m{Vd1:.2f} KN\033[m')
            print(f'Resistência da zona de apoio: \033[33m{Vrd1:.2f} KN\033[m')
        return

    # textos e CheckButtons de escolha
    lb_escolaSolucao = Label(frame_sugestoes, text="ESCOLHA A SOLUÇÃO:", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), pady=10,
                             bd=3, fg="#1E90FF", anchor="center")
    lb_escolaSolucao.grid(row=0, column=3)
    ck_Alargura = Checkbutton(frame_sugestoes, text="Aumentar largura", font=("Segoe UI", 12), command=ck1)
    ck_Alargura.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
    ck_Afck = Checkbutton(frame_sugestoes, text="Aumentar o Fck", font=("Segoe UI", 12), command=ck2)
    ck_Afck.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)

    # Entrada de dados
    en_largura = Entry(frame_sugestoes, font=("Ce/ntury Gothic", 11), textvariable=raid11, bd=5, insertwidth=4,
                       width=12, bg="#1E90FF", justify="right")
    en_largura.grid(row=1, column=4)
    en_fck = Entry(frame_sugestoes, font=("Century Gothic", 11), textvariable=raid12, bd=5, insertwidth=4,
                   width=12, bg="#1E90FF", justify="right")
    en_fck.grid(row=2, column=4)

    # botões reset e confirmar
    bt_reset = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="RESET", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=16, pady=0,
                      bd=2, width=7, command=reset)
    bt_reset.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=E)
    bt_confirmar1 = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="CONFIRMAR", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=16,
                           pady=0, bd=2, width=7, command=confirmar1)
    bt_confirmar1.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=W)

if Vrd < Vd:
    bws = str("Utilize uma largura mínima de viga de %.f cm" % ((Vd / (0.2 * he * fcd)) * 100))
    fcks = str("Utilize um Fck mínimo de %.f MPa" % (1.4 * Vd / (200 * bw * he)))

    # Janela de verificação de cisalhamento
    verificacao1 = Tk()
    verificacao1.title("ERRO NA VERIFICAÇÃO")
    verificacao1.geometry("+300+100")

    # Frames
    frame_top1 = Frame(verificacao1)
    frame_top1.pack()
    frame_sugestoes = Frame(verificacao1)
    frame_sugestoes.pack(side=LEFT)

    # Textos
    lb_alerta1 = Label(frame_top1, text="A ESTRUTURA NÃO SUPORTA O EFEITO DE CISALHAMENTO NO CONCRETO",
                       font=("Arial", 13, "bold"), pady=12, fg="#1E90FF")
    lb_alerta1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    lb_psugestoes = Label(frame_sugestoes, text="POSSÍVEIS SOLUÇÕES", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), pady=10, bd=3,
                          fg="#1E90FF")
    lb_psugestoes.grid(row=0, column=0)
    lb_largura = Label(frame_sugestoes, text=bws, font=("Segoe UI", 12))
    lb_largura.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    lb_fck = Label(frame_sugestoes, text=fcks, font=("Segoe UI", 12))
    lb_fck.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    lb_quest1 = Label(frame_sugestoes, text="Deseja aplicar alguma solução? ", font=("Segoe UI", 12))
    lb_quest1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
    lb_linha1 = Label(frame_sugestoes)
    lb_linha1.grid(row=3, column=0)

    # botões - SIM/NÃO
    bt_sim1 = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="SIM", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=8, pady=0, bd=2,
                     width=5, command=bt_click_sim1)
    bt_sim1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)
    bt_nao1 = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="NÃO", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=8, pady=0, bd=2,
                     width=5, command=bt_click_nao1)
    bt_nao1.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)
    verificacao1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Para poder responder melhor essa pergunta, precisamos saber "o que tem fora do if".  Que código seta as variáveis `Vrd` e `Vd`?

Comment: certo.. @jsbueno todo esse if está contido em uma função que eu chamei de confirmar que está atribuída a um botão também chamado de CONFIRMAR. Vou editar a pergunta e inserir o código acima do if.

Comment: Que tipo de erros estaria gerando? Relacionados a lógica, design ou estruturação?